# Index Item of array not getting deleted

Tags: reactjs

I've just noticed a problem with my UI where clicking the delete button at a particular index doesn't delete that particular record and instead ends up deleting data situated at a different index. I'm quite clueless as to why this is happening. The list seems to render properly in order but then it all goes south when I try deleting it. My first deduction of this issue for a split second was that this had something to do with the API that I'm fetching the data from but then I realized that the data was getting rendered as it should and as it was defined. I would like to know what I can do to ensure that I'm deleting the data that I've clicked and not anything else. Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Task = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setTodos(data)
            })
    }, []);

    const deleteTodo = (index) => {
        const temp = [...todos];
        temp.splice(index, 1);
        setTodos(temp);
        console.log(index);
        // console.log(`newData : ${arr} || newLength : ${arr.length}`);
        console.log(`newLength : ${todos.length}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table className='table'>
                <tbody>
                    {todos.map((key, value) => (
                        <tr key={key.id}>
                            <td>{todos[value].id}</td>
                            <td>{todos[value].title}</td>
                            <td>{`${todos[value].completed}`}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className='btn btn-danger ' onClick={() => deleteTodo(key.id)}> Delete </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Add Task</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Task;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `key.id` to `deleteTodo` and then delete the item in the todo with index of `key.id` and it may not as the same as the index of the item, you should pass the index of item to the `deleteTodo`

like this :

```
{todos.map((todoItem, todoIndex) => (
                    <tr key={todoItem.id}>
                        <td>{todoItem.id}</td>
                        <td>{todoItem.title}</td>
                        <td>{`${todoItem.completed}`}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button className='btn btn-danger ' onClick={() => deleteTodo(todoIndex)}> Delete </button>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                ))}
```

Comment: Add the fact that according to MDN keys from map() are considered complex and may not be in the desired order (read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Another approach to solving the issue would be to leverage ES6 in the deleteTodo function, by passing todoItem.Id as value and then use filter.

const newTodo = todos.filter(todo=> todo.id !== index); where index is the value passed to the function from the button onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Mehtod `.splice()` needs index of element as start index, but you are sending an `id`. So, if id is 1 you will remove element on position 1, what is other element.

You can do `.findIndex` of element by id inside your delete function.
There is working example [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-tu-ns4m9?file=/src/TaskList.js)